# Python running unittest n times with unittest and generate report with htmltestrunner

Tags: python, html, selenium, unit-testing, report

class Espera(unittest.TestCase):

```
def setUp(self):
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\ricar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\geckodriver.exe")
    driver.get("http://goodstartbook.com/pruebas/")

def test1(self):
    espera = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    boton = espera.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"proceed")))
    if boton is not None:
        boton.click()
        print("Succesful")

    time.sleep(3)

def tearDown(self):
    driver.quit()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    for i in range(1, 2):
        unittest.main(exit=False)
        print(i)
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='C:/Users/ricar/Documents/GrillOnBox/PythonScripts'))

Comment: can you explicitly state the issue at hand?

Comment: I just want to run test1 several times. But I want to know each time if it passed or not. After several times of testing. I want to run unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='path')), so I can generate a unique report of all the tests I did